# Помощь дилетанту. На чем посоветуете создать сайт

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток! ;)
Работаю в школе на должности инженер-электроник (да, вот такое забавное название).

Дали задание сделать школьный сайт.

Опыта в создании нормальных полноценных сайтов нет. В институте принимал участие в написании web-сервиса на pl/sql, и как-то с ужасом это вспоминаю, сколько там было тыс. строк кода для простых на мой взгляд операций ;)

Уважаемые разработчики! Посоветуйте для девственного разума и такого же опыта, как и на чем сделать школьный сайт. Чтобы было увлекательно и учить и программировать.

Просто в интернете столько всяких технологий и фреймворков, что без советов сложно выбирать. =)

Знаю HTML и CSS на базовом уровне. 
Опыт с СУБД это Oracle и MySQL, но и опытом это не назвать ;)
Программирование тоже самые азы, ни какого определенного ЯП не знаю, только общие принципы.

В какой ОС работать не принципиально, у меня тут целый зоопарк на работе windows, linux, macos =)

Заранее спасибо за ответы и надеюсь на добрые советы! =))

Comment: Ответ на вопрос сводится к выбору серверного языка и выбору сервера SQL. Однозначного критерия для выбора и того и другого нет. Вам скорее всего посоветуют PHP+MySQL. Или ASP.NET MVC + MS Sql Server. или Node.js + mongo. Причем объективно обосновать ответ никто не сможет, и в выборе это вам не поможет. Так что берите ASP.NET MVC (потому что я хорошо знаю ASP.NET!). А вопрос лучше оставить закрытым.

Answer (score 4):

Если нет опыта с PHP, то лучше всего взять какой-нибудь движок, например Drupal или Joomla. У обоих движков есть большие сообщества и очень много информации, которую легко найти. 
Так как есть знания по HTML и CSS, то будет просто сделать под них шаблон, а весь остальной сайт собрать из готовых модулей. 
ИМХО, для школьного сайта большего не надо. 
Если же хотите писать с нуля - то PHP лучший выбор, потому что писать на JAVA или APS.NET - надо будет очень много учить и за многим следить, что для начала - сложно.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно быстро сделать сайт, вам поможет `CMS (Content management system)`, например, `Joomla, Drupal` или даже `WordPress` сгодится. Из знаний понадобится только CSS и документация по `CMS`, что бы шаблон сверстать.

Если вы хотите по ходу научиться программировать, то надо начать хотя бы с изучения `php`, как минимум, а потом уже браться за фреймворки.

PS.(При работе с `CMS` в большинстве случаев программирование не нужно).

Answer (score 0):

DLE, Joomla, WordPress - понятные и легкие в освоении движки.
ModX чуть сложнее.